# Is it possible to do full URL logging in routers (ie not just subdomain level)?

Tags: router, dns, opendns

I'm using OpenDNS to log websites visited. But I only get the domains/subdomains visited. Is it possible to log the full URL visited (for example https://superuser.com/questions/ask, not just superuser.com)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full URL is one level higher up in the protocol stack than just the domain name. In order to log the full URL, you need something which can scan the HTTP protocol.

The easiest way to do this is to set up a (transparent) proxy server and have all web traffic routed through this proxy. This will give you a log with the full URL's.

An easy to set up proxy on Linux is [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Your web server almost certainly has logging capabilities, why not use that?  Then you can use something like analog, webalizer or visitors to analyze the logs.

You can't do that just through DNS queries, the full URL visited is not available that way.  Only the domains/subdomains can be captured, as you are seeing.